# LeetCode 1032: Stream of Characters

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you have time and would like to review, please do so. Thank you!

> #### Problem
>
> Implement the `StreamChecker` class as follows:
>
> - `StreamChecker(words)`: Constructor, init the data structure with the given words.
> - `query(letter)`: returns true if and only if for some k >= 1, the last k characters queried (in order from oldest to newest, including this letter just queried) spell one of the words in the given list.
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```
> StreamChecker streamChecker = new StreamChecker(["cd","f","kl"]); // init the dictionary.
> streamChecker.query('a');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('b');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('c');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('d');          // return true, because 'cd' is in the wordlist
> streamChecker.query('e');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('f');          // return true, because 'f' is in the wordlist
> streamChecker.query('g');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('h');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('i');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('j');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('k');          // return false
> streamChecker.query('l');          // return true, because 'kl' is in the wordlist
> ```
>
> #### Note:
>
> - \$1 \le \text{words.length} \le 2000\$
> - \$1 \le \text{words[i].length} \le 2000\$
> - Words will only consist of lowercase English letters.
> - Queries will only consist of lowercase English letters.
> - The number of queries is at most 40000.

#### Code

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class Trie {
    std::unordered_map<char, Trie*> alphabet_map;
    bool is_word;

public:
    Trie() {
        is_word = false;
    }

    // Inserts in the trie
    void insert(const std::string word) {
        if (word.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Trie* temp_trie = this;

        for (auto letter : word) {
            if (temp_trie->alphabet_map.find(letter) != temp_trie->alphabet_map.end()) {
                temp_trie = temp_trie->alphabet_map[letter];

            } else {
                temp_trie->alphabet_map[letter] = new Trie();
                temp_trie = temp_trie->alphabet_map[letter];
            }
        }

        temp_trie->is_word = true;
    }

    // Searches the word in the trie
    bool search(const std::string word) {
        if (word.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        Trie* temp_trie = this;

        for (auto letter : word) {
            if (temp_trie->alphabet_map.find(letter) == temp_trie->alphabet_map.end()) {
                return false;
            }

            temp_trie = temp_trie->alphabet_map[letter];

            if (temp_trie->is_word) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return temp_trie->is_word;
    }
};

class StreamChecker {
    Trie trie_stream;
    std::string string_stream = "";
    int word_length = 0;

public:
    StreamChecker(const std::vector<std::string>& words) {
        for (auto word : words) {
            std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
            word_length = std::max(word_length, (int) word.length());
            trie_stream.insert(word);
        }
    }


    bool query(const char letter) {
        string_stream = letter + string_stream;

        if (string_stream.length() > word_length) {
            string_stream.pop_back();
        }

        return trie_stream.search(string_stream);
    }
};
```

#### Reference

LeetCode has a template for answering questions. There is usually a class named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename. For this question, the template is:

```
class StreamChecker {
public:
    StreamChecker(vector<string>& words) {
        
    }
    
    bool query(char letter) {
        
    }
};

/**
 * Your StreamChecker object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * StreamChecker* obj = new StreamChecker(words);
 * bool param_1 = obj->query(letter);
 */
```

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/stream-of-characters/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/stream-of-characters/discuss/)
- [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Template

You can't rename functions; but can you change their signature? i.e.

```
StreamChecker(vector<string>& words) {
```

would be better as

```
StreamChecker(const vector<string> &words) {
```

Similarly,

```
void insert(const std::string word) {
```

should be

```
void insert(const std::string &word) {
```

The same for `search`.

Also, the `const` in

```
bool query(const char letter) {
```

isn't as important, since `letter` is itself an immutable letter. It would be more important if this were a reference or pointer.

Finally, your `search` method does not modify members, so:

```
bool search(const std::string &word) const {
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Reinderien said:

## Move `class Trie` inside `class StreamChecker`

Your `class Trie` is not a generic class, but rather a specialized trie implementation specifically for `StreamChecker`. You can move it inside `class StreamChecker`, so that it is clear that they belong to each other, and so that `class Trie` does not pollute the global namespace:

```
class StreamChecker {
    class Trie {
        ...
    };

    Trie trie_stream;
    ...
};
```

## Store `Trie`s by value

Your `class Trie` has a memory leak: it calls `new Trie()`, but there is no corresponding `delete` in sight. You could write a destructor that iterates over `alphabet_map` and calls `delete` on the values, or even use `std::unique_ptr` to track ownership of the memory, but there is no need for this at all. After all, `std::map` already takes care of managing the memory necessary to store the keys and values. So remove that pointer and write:

```
class Trie {
    std::unordered_map<char, Trie> alphabet_map;
    ...
    void insert(const std::string &word) {
        if (word.empty()) {
            return;
        }

        Trie *temp_trie = this;

        for (auto letter: word) {
             temp_trie = &temp_trie->alphabet_map[letter];
        }

        temp_trie->is_word = true;
    }
};
```

Note that in `search()` you need to do similar modifications, but there you do need to explicitly check whether the `letter` is present in the `alphabet_map`.